# Incorrect time on .ics invitations

Tags: ios, icloud

All of my calendars are on iCloud (synched to Outlook 2013 on Win7, and on my iPad and iPhone). At least most of the time (possibly every time) I receive an .ics meeting invitation, the time is incorrect. This seems to be exclusively tied to time zone differences, but makes no sense.

For instance, I received an invitation yesterday from someone in California (PST). They had set the meeting for 08:00 their time. I am in EST (+3 hours). The invitation (and the resulting calendar item after I accepted) show as 10:00 for me. Clearly this is neither my time zone nor the originator's. When I look at the entry in iCloud, it shows a "Floating" time zone. I cannot change the time of the event in any of my tools (Outlook, iCloud, or iOS), presumably because it of restriction of permissions on events created from an invitation. I also cannot delete the item (without rejecting the invitation), so my only recourse has been to create a duplicate entry at the correct time, hoping I won't be confused by this in 6 weeks on the meeting date.

Is there any way for me to handle these .ics invitations and have them end up showing properly in my calendar?

Answer (score 1):

http://lanyrd.com/help/timezones/

iPhone calendar settings live in Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -  select "Time Zone Override".

I turned it off and it resolved the issue with the time zones